# Start and final dialogs in XP do not show bitmaps

Tags: dialog, installation, wix

I have an installer, it works fine in Windows 7, but in XP some of predefined WiX dialogs (start and final) do not show bitmaps but only text.

How to fix this?

PS. The matter is in JPGs. On W7 it works, but not on XP. Probably format is bad for XP.

Comment: Normally there should be no difference - we have installers generated by wix that are used on XP, Vista and Windows 7 and we don't have such a problem. Are you testing the exact same MSI file on XP? Do you customize the default bitmaps as described [in the wix documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_customizations.htm), or are you doing something else? Are the bitmap dimensions correct? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: This isn't correct. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

I have experienced the same problems using JPEG for `WixUIDialogBmp` and `WixUIBannerBmp` (using WiX 3.6).

The installer on Windows7 displays the images correctly:

[image: Installer on Windows7]

The **same installer** on Vista doesn't show the images:

[image]

After converting the JPEGs to Bitmaps the installer works correctly on Vista:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use bitmaps (.bmp) for banner and dialog images in WiX.